# How to understand this step in the proof for integral comparison test?

Tags: sequences-and-series

In a proof for the integral test, where $a_n = f(n)$ and $f$ is a continuous decreasing positive function, one of the steps claims:

> $$a_1 +  \sum^N_{n=2} a_n \le a_1 + \sum_{n=2}^N \int^n_{n-1} f(x) \, dx$$

Why is this necessarily true?

Does not the left hand side of the inequality takes a left hand Riemann sums from $2$ to $N$, which is larger than the integral of the same span. Why does the sum of the integrals on the right hand side, which starts from $1$ instead of $2$, necessarily become larger?

From section $3.3$ of "[*Infinite Series*](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/series.pdf)" by Keith Conrad.

Comment: Should the lower limit of the sum on the right hand side be $n=2$ instead of $n-2$?

Comment: I changed \underline{<} to \le. That is standard.

Comment: This is not about Riemann sums: you don't have a mesh of a partition approaching $0. \qquad$

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

We have that

$$(\forall n>1)\;\;  (\forall x\in [n-1,n] )$$
$$ a_n=f (n)\leq f (x)$$

cause $f $ is decreasing at $[n-1,n] $.
$f $ is continuous 
thus by integration from $n-1$ to $n $, we get

$$\int_{n-1}^n a_n dx\leq \int_{n-1}^nf (x)dx $$

or
$$(n-(n-1))a_n\leq \int_{n-1}^n f (x)dx $$

and by sum from $2$ to $N $, you finish.

Answer (score 0):

So we have to prove this:

$\sum_{a}^{b}{f(x)} < \int_{a-1}^{b}{f(x).dx}$

Since the integration starts from $a-1$, this inequality is correct.[image]

Take a look at the diagram above(a = 2):

As you can see, the rectangles(the sigma part) is always under the curve.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of viewing the left hand side of the inequality as a left hand Riemann sum from $2$ to $N$, view it as a right hand Riemann sum from $1$ to $N$.  This is because on the right hand side of the inequality, you are integrating from $n-1$ to $n$, which means you are really integrating starting from $n=1$.

The right hand Riemann Sum of a decreasing function is smaller than the integral of the same span.

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to be: Why is $\displaystyle a_n = f(n) \le \int_{n-1}^n f(x)\,dx\text{ ?}$

The function is **decreasing.** That implies that:

$$
\text{if } n-1\le x\le n \text{ then } f(x) \ge f(n).
$$
Therefore $\displaystyle \int_{n-1}^n f(x)\,dx \ge \int_{n-1}^n f(n)\,dx = f(n) = a_n.$

Comment: It is exactly what i wrote.